# What is a correct way to send an array in POST request using Volley?

Tags: android, post, request, android-volley

When I use Postman, I am getting correct response (server processes "categories" as an array) from the server using request description below:
[image: Postman request body]

with header:
[image: Postman request headers]

This request has this raw representation:

```
POST /api/items HTTP/1.1
Host: www1.
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c18f92ee-2f36-f4dd-2963-6bc6d1db0bdf

items=247642&categories%5B%5D=12&categories%5B%5D=11
```

My question is how to represent described request to fire it correctly using Volley library. I have tried many variants, for example:

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    return "items=247642&categories%5B%5D=12".getBytes();
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String,String> headers = super.getHeaders();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return headers;
}
```

but all of them either don't encode "categories" as array (so server doesn't take this variable in account at all) or make encoding in incorrect way, so server can't obtain values of this array.

**UPDATE:**

I've just tried to fire this request using OkHttp and it was absolutely correct (as in the case with Postman above):

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "items=247642&categories%5B%5D=10&categories%5B%5D=9");
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://www1...")
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .build();
```

That means only one thing: Volley processes raw request bodies in some other way (maybe an incorrect one) or there is some subtle config in Volley missing to perform such requests correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should admit that problem described in the question is mostly based on the server's logic. By dumping request bodies from Volley and OkHttp and comparing them step by step I could find out that they have difference only in one header - `Content-Type`. In OkHttp it was look like:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
```

while in Volley it was:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

So looks like it was a kind of strict check of headers on the server. To make Volley's headers be equal to OkHttp's, I had to remove overriding of `getHeaders()` method in request and return body type description in a `getBodyContentType()` method:

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}
```

I can't say that my question is completely solved, because there still can be more answers about how to add arrays in POST-request bodies using more elegant ways (without raw bodies and other formats - for example JSON).